# svn:externals - using wildcards

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm using svn 1.7.

I have a folder which is a collaction of DLL's from various 3rd parties. Some 3rd parties contain several DLLs.

Is there're possibility to use wildcard in svn:external (e.g. *.dll) or should I name each file individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** define SRC as single file in case of file-based externals

You **can** svn:external the whole dir at some location and get access to all files in linked directory

Comment: Is there other than file-based externals?

Comment: @dimba - you can use directory as target (as opposed to file-target)